# Facebook publish to feed not publishing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish a post from an Activity taking an example from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/publish-to-feed/. It authorizes the app to post on the user's wall but it's not publishing the post to the news feed or wall and consequently I'm not seeing the success alert with the posted story ID. What might be the issue? Keep in mind that I'd also like the session to be valid before the user navigates to this activity, since the login form is on another activity, without the user having to login to Facebook in this activity. Here's the code:

```
public class Post extends SherlockActivity {

    private Button shareButton;
    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays
            .asList("publish_actions");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ad_details);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                    PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
        }
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                publishStory();
            }
        });
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
            if (pendingPublishReauthorization
                    && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
                publishStory();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void publishStory() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null) {

            // Check for publish permissions
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Adbionic Mobile");
            postParams.putString("caption",
                    "Caption");
            postParams.putString("description", "Facebook SDK testing");
            postParams.putString("link",
                    "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
            postParams
                    .putString("picture",
                            "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

            Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        String TAG = null;
                        Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), postId,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
                    HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The session is not valid",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
            Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override onActivityResult in your Post activity, and call Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(...)

Comment: How do I add the override and where do I call the Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(...)